# Best Practices: Redundant data or multiple joins?

Tags: sql, linq-to-entities

Suppose you have the following tables: **Orders**, **Customers**, **Events**, **Lines**, and **LineAssignments**.  The only table that I can modify is the LineAssignments table.

- Event 1 <---> * Orders
- Customer 1 <---> * Orders
- Order 1 <---> * LineAssignments
- Line 1 <---> * LineAssignments

Different pages display different combinations of info with the line assignments.  For example, on some pages I only display the event info with the line assignments, while on other pages I display the order info with them, etc.

Basically, whenever I add a new line assignment, should I also store the *EventID*, *CustomerID*, and *OrderID* too, or should I only store the *OrderID*, then do multiple joins to get the other data.  Would it be better to create a view that joins these tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simply a question of performance. Generally, you should stick to the 3NF, i.e. no redundancy. Whereas this gives very tight and elegant data structures, it might also lead to heavy performance issues.

This is usually the case if your database is both for productive and historical data, i.e. grows over time.

When issuing the joined queries, your RDBMS will load as much information as possible into memory, usually index information to speed up your query. Now, if your indexes are so big that they don't fit into memory, your RDBMS (no, the OS in fact) will have to swap, which is a performance killer.

The real deal (in my eyes) is to completely separate productive data (open / unpaid orders for example) from historic data. The historic data can and should be optimized for fast retrieval as nothing changes anymore and hard discs are cheap.

Productive data should be nice and tight (3.NF). Whenever a piece of information is not productive anymore (order is paid, parts are delivered etc.) it will be removed from the productive database and transferred to the historical data.

Get information on the topic 'data warehouse' in case you're not yet familiar with it and read about the concepts. It's quite easy to understand.

Answer (score 4):

I tend to follow the school of thought that data should only be represented once in a database.  This means, in your place, I would attempt to get what I need from multiple joins and only store OrderID.

The reason why I would do this is if there's any chance that the data stored in the other tables (the data you copied over to the LineAssignments table) is updated, the copied data would be wrong.  I don't see it being super likely that the data in the other tables would change, but in the off-chance that it does... You'd be better off with the joins than potentially incorrect data.